# Retrofit List of object assigns null to data

Tags: android, retrofit

This is how my `JSON` response looks

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "PhName": "sample string 2",
    "Longitude": 3.1,
    "Latitude": 4.1,
    "ApplicationUserId": "sample string 5"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "PhName": "sample string 2",
    "Longitude": 3.1,
    "Latitude": 4.1,
    "ApplicationUserId": "sample string 5"
  }
]
```

this is my retrofit interface call

```
@GET("/api/GPS")
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json"
})
Call<List<UserResponse>> search(@Query("search") String search,
                        @Header("Authorization") String auth);
```

Pojo Class

```
public class UserResponse {
    @SerializedName("Id")
    int id;

    @SerializedName("UserName")
    String phName;

    @SerializedName("Longitude")
    int lon;

    @SerializedName("Latitude")
    int lat;

    @SerializedName("ApplicationUserId")
    String appUserId;

//getters and setters
}
```

Retrofit declaration

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(PerformLogin.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Getting data and using it

```
MyApiEndpointInterface apiService =
                retrofit.create(MyApiEndpointInterface.class);
        Call<List<UserResponse>> call = apiService.search(query,"Bearer "+token);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<UserResponse>> call, Response<List<UserResponse>> response) {
                List<UserResponse> userList = response.body();
                Log.w("My App", response.message());
                for (int i = 0; i <userList.size() ; i++) {
                    Log.w("My App", userList.get(i).getPhName()+""+i);
                }



                //mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),userList);
                //mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<UserResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w("My App", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

my response

```
W/My App: OK
W/My App: null 0
W/My App: null 1
W/My App: null 2
W/My App: null 3
```

In this case I am suppose to receive four result from the search and the names are giving me null.

Is there anything I am doing wrong or a better solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong serialize name. You are trying to assign value from node `UserName` to `phName`, which is not available. So, you are getting null.

Change

```
@SerializedName("UserName")
String phName;
```

with

```
@SerializedName("PhName") // change this
String phName;
```

Also, `@SerializedName("Id")` should be `@SerializedName("id")`. It's case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Your `SerializedName` fields and the JSON fields don't match.

JSON: `id` -> GSON: `Id`
JSON: `PhName` -> GSON: `UserName`

Those two don't add up. You have to alter your annotations accordingly:

```
@SerializedName("id")
int id;

@SerializedName("PhName")
String phName;
```